# Changing color of a windowmanager service

Tags: android, android-service, android-windowmanager

I have an interesting question. I have a WindowManager inside of a Service. Right now the windowmanager covers the screen and is translucent so you will be able to do other things under the window manager.

In the application that starts the windowmanager service. I would like to change the color of the background by pressing the button change color. However im not able to get that view or have no idea on how to get it to be able to use it.
Here is the github of the project, I hope someone can help me out, if you need more info please let me know.

there is a **onClick** method in the **MainActivity** **setDiffColor** to change the color you can use R.color.colorAccent to the color to change to that

https://github.com/juangdiaz/windowmanagerservice

**This is how i start the service, in the MainActivity**

```
public void setOn(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "opening window", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        setOn.setEnabled(false);
        sd.start(sensorManager);
        startService(new Intent(this, FloatingWidgetService.class));
    }
```

**Stopping the service, in the MainActivity**

```
public void setOff(View v) {
    setOn.setEnabled(true);
    stopService(new Intent(getApplication(), FloatingWidgetService.class));

}
```

**Changing the color, in the MainActivity**

```
    public void setDiffColor(View v) {
R.color.colorAccent
        //TODO: Change the WindowManagers Color


    }
```

**Floatingwidgetservice class**

```
package com.bluetooth.juandiaz.bluetoothconnectivity.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.bluetooth.juandiaz.bluetoothconnectivity.R;




public class FloatingWidgetService extends Service {


    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private View widget;

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        widget = new View(this);

        final LayoutInflater factory = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        widget = factory.inflate(R.layout.floating_widget, null);
        widget.setAlpha(0.50f);


        params= new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        windowManager.addView(widget, params);


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (widget != null)
            windowManager.removeView(widget);
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: please clarify. You're talking about a service and an activity, but it's not clear what you want. Also provide code!

Comment: the code is in the repo, i made it simple so its easy to follow, in the Main activity I have a service and when i start the service is creates a WindowManager that stays in the screen as long as you dont stop the service. I want to be able to change the background color of it by pressing the button on the mainactivity

Comment: please post relevant parts of the code here, as 3rd party links might get deleted in the future (not to talk about that, that after we fix the problem, you'll commit the fix, so nobody will see the problem even if the new version is there)

Comment: gotcha doing that right now

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this using GreenRobot and it works well

Since is hard to reach the View from a service, I attached an Event to the service. this way i would be able to change the color whenever i do any changes in the Event listener. it will update the view on that point.

this code is in the FloatingWidgetService.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

}
public void onEvent(WindowEvent event){
        Toast.makeText(this, "event fired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        widget.setBackgroundResource(event.getColor());

    }
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (widget != null) {
        windowManager.removeView(widget);
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}
```

then in the MainActivity I did

```
public void setDiffColor(View v) {

    EventBus.getDefault().post(new WindowEvent(R.color.colorAccent));
}
```

And created a POJO for the EventBus

```
public class WindowEvent {

public int getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
}

private int color;

public WindowEvent(int color) {
         this.color = color;
    }
```

}

Comment: For posterity, could you give some more details in your answer?